# yii2 refresh captcha when validation fails

Tags: yii2

I am using the default Captcha Widget with advanced Yii2 template.I want to refresh the Captcha Image if validation fails.I tried with trigger as mentioned in previous trails,but i want to refresh image whenever captcha fails.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'captcha')->widget(Captcha::classname(), [ 'template' => '{image} <a href="javascript:;" onclick="captchRef()" >Refresh</a>{input}', ])?>

<script>
    function captchRef(){ 
        $("img[id$='-captcha-image']").trigger('click');
    } 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            'success': function(html){
                jQuery("#yw0").attr("src",html)
            }, 
            'url':'captcha?refresh=1', 
            'cache':false 
        }); 
        return false; 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: In my view file : <?= $form->field($model, 'captcha')->widget(Captcha::classname(), [
            'template' => '{image} <a href="javascript:;" onclick="captchRef()" >Refresh</a>{input}',
        ])?> <script> function captchRef(){
    $("img[id$='-captcha-image']").trigger('click');
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        'success':function(html){jQuery("#yw0").attr("src",html)},
        'url':'captcha?refresh=1',
        'cache':false
    });
    return false;
    
  });</script>

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [testLimit](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captchaaction.html#$testLimit-detail). You can set `testLimit` value to 1.